# How to make slave server take over VIP when master reboot with "keepalived"

Tags: keepalived

I'm using [keepalived](http://www.keepalived.org/) and read through the [keepalived.conf.SYNOPSIS](https://github.com/acassen/keepalived/blob/master/doc/keepalived.conf.SYNOPSIS). I tried everything, it feels like. What ever I do, I can't make my backup server take over the VIP faster then 10 sec, when the master server is rebooted.

The **keepalived.conf** I'm using looks like:

```
global_defs
{
  # don't run scripts configured to be run as root if any part of the path
  # is writable by a non-root user.
  enable_script_security 1

  # delay for second set of gratuitous ARPs after transition to MASTER
  # seconds, default 5, 0 for no second set
  vrrp_garp_master_delay 0

  # number of gratuitous ARP messages to send at a time after transition to
  # MASTER
  # default 5
  vrrp_garp_master_repeat 1

  # delay for second set of gratuitous ARPs after lower priority advert
  # received when MASTER
  vrrp_garp_lower_prio_delay 0

  # number of gratuitous ARP messages to send at a time after lower priority
  # advert received when MASTER
  vrrp_garp_lower_prio_repeat 1

  # minimum time interval for refreshing gratuitous ARPs while MASTER
  # secs, default 0 (no refreshing)
  vrrp_garp_master_refresh 10

  # number of gratuitous ARP messages to send at a time while MASTER
  # default 1
  vrrp_garp_master_refresh_repeat 1

  # delay in ms between gratuitous ARP messages sent on an interface
  # decimal, seconds (resolution usecs). Default 0.
  vrrp_garp_interval 0.001

  # delay in ms between unsolicited NA messages sent on an interface
  # decimal, seconds (resolution usecs). Default 0.
  vrrp_gna_interval 0.001
}

vrrp_instance VI_1
{
  state             {{STATE}}
  interface         {{INTERFACE}}
  virtual_router_id {{VRID}}
  priority          {{PRIORITY}}
  advert_int        1
  debug             4
  authentication
  {
    auth_type PASS
    auth_pass {{PASSWORD}}
  }
  virtual_ipaddress
  {
    {{IP_VIRTUAL}}
  }
}
```

Comment: You haven't set `advert_int`? And 0.001ms is _very_ short (1 microsecond), I wouldn't be surprised if you can only enter integers there.

Comment: @wurtel `advert_int` is set, the `0.001` I tried with multiple values, with and with out setting it as well.